# adding data from text file to listbox

Tags: c#, file, streamreader

i am having problems with loading in data from a text file (notepad txt file) and displaying it in a listbox. the following is my code, not sure why it doesn't load the data

```
private void loadData() {
        try {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("visits.txt"))     //Reads in file
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    string[] data = line.Split(',');               //Splits the lines up when there is a ,
                    lstDeliveries.Items.Add(data[0] + ", " + data[1] + ", " + data[2]);
                    lstPickups.Items.Add(data[3] + ", " + data[4]);                                              
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException) {
            MessageBox.Show("The file was not found!!");      //Provides error if file not found
            Environment.Exit(0);                        //Closes application 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could at least provide the description of your problem, i.e. exception message

Comment: i didnt have any exception messages

Comment: You might want to add a Debug statement to check if line holds anything `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide what kind of problems you have. I assume some lines in your file have unexpected format. Add condition to verify that data array has at least 5 items:

```
string[] data = line.Split(',');
if (data.Length >= 5)
{             
   lstDeliveries.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", data[0], data[1], data[2]);
   lstPickups.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}, {1}", data[3], data[4]); 
}
```

Also `String.Format` is a better option to format strings.

Comment: @littledevils326 because you are trying to access fifth item in array `data[4]`

Comment: thanks it worked. maybe im stupid but i still dont understand why you need if (data.Length >= 5)

Comment: @littledevils326 because if `data` contains less than 5 elements, you'll get `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: ... which, might, under certain circumstances, get swallowed by the framework.